# How to create a GUI installer that deploys a WinUI app?

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

I'm working on a WinUI desktop application, using Visual Studio as a dev environment.

I want to create an installer that would let the user choose the installation directory through screen dialogs.

By following this documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/single-project-msix?tabs=csharp
I'm able to produce an `.appinstaller` (which doesn't work) and an `.msix`,
but the doc never mention any sort of user configuration or GUI during the installation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's at MSIX document. Does [Using an embedded App Installer file to update your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/how-to-embed-an-appinstaller-file) work for you?

Comment: You cannot modify the installation experience of an MSIX package to include custom dialogs. This is not supported and neither is choosing the installation directory of the app.